# SQL Server Trigger To Prevent Database Drop

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012, eventtrigger

I would like to put a server level trigger in place to prevent dropping of any database that is not a database snapshot. At first blush the below appears as if it should work but it never does. I've tried reversing the logic and that didn't help. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(100),
        @eventData XML;

SET @eventData = EVENTDATA();           
SELECT  @DBName = @eventData.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'SYSNAME');

RAISERROR('Attempting delete of %s.', 10, 1, @DBName);

IF @DBName IN (SELECT name
               FROM sys.databases 
               WHERE source_database_id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('[%s] was successfully dropped.', 10, 1, @DBname) WITH LOG;
    END;
ELSE         
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('[%s] cannot be deleted without first disabling the server trigger "tgr_prevent_db_drop".', 10, 1, @DBname) WITH LOG;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

The RAISERROR at the top always confirms the correct database (e.g. the one being deleted) and when I run the SELECT from sys.databases manually it always returns the appropriate data. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, this always falls into the "..was successfully dropped" section for both true databases and their database snapshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried getting this to work as well, but ran into too many permission obstacles due to sys.databases only returning values visible by the current user. (And i couldn't get a reliable enough generic solution with "Executing As" attempts.)

Eventually i just decided to use the database name as a filter. Example:

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(100),
        @eventData XML;

SET @eventData = EVENTDATA();           
SELECT  @DBName = @eventData.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'SYSNAME');

RAISERROR('Attempting delete of %s.', 10, 1, @DBName);

IF Right(@DBName, 9) <> '_SnapShot' --Checking via db name due to permissions affecting sys.databases
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('[%s] was successfully dropped.', 10, 1, @DBname) WITH LOG;
    END;
ELSE         
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('[%s] cannot be deleted without first disabling the server trigger "tgr_prevent_db_drop".', 10, 1, @DBname) WITH LOG;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

this condition is always true..

```
IF @DBName IN (SELECT name
               FROM sys.databases 
               WHERE source_database_id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('[%s] was successfully dropped.', 10, 1, @DBname) WITH LOG;
    END;
```

so ,your database will be dropped no matter what..Instead move below else clause  to above block

```
RAISERROR('[%s] cannot be deleted without first disabling the server trigger "tgr_prevent_db_drop".', 10, 1, @DBname) WITH LOG;
        ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Hi @TheGameIswar, I am not tracking. If the database is a snapshot it will have a value in the source_database_id column and appear in the SELECT so the condition should always be true then. If it isn't a snapshot, source_database_id has to be NULL so I'd expect this to evaluate as false. If I run this outside of the DDL trigger, it works as expected. It is only inside the DDL trigger that it fails. Ultimately I want to allow snapshot deletion but prevent parent database deletion.

Comment: @PseudoToad, the sys.databases has the issue of returning values based on the user's permissions. If your trigger isn't seeing the snapshot databases in sys.databases, then the trigger is executing as a user that doesn't have permissions to it.